# Мокап для подключения навбар_меню бустрап3 на WordPress wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php

Tags: php, wordpress, bootstrap

Есть подключенный мокап для навбар-меню bootstrap3 под ворпресс:[wp-bootstrap-navwalker](https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker)

Все это дело подключил как положено и менюшка активно выводится:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </button>
                                <span class="navbar-brand">МЕНЮ</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
                                <?php /* Primary navigation */
                                wp_nav_menu( array(
                                    'menu' => 'primary',
                                    'depth' =>  2,
                                    'container' => false,
                                    'strcasecmp' => 1,
                                    'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav center',
                                    'fallback_cb' => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                                    //Process nav menu using our custom nav walker
                                    'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                                );
                                wp_nav_menu( array(
                                    'menu' => 'primary',
                                    'depth' =>  0,
                                    'container' => false,
                                    'menu_class' => 'dropdown-menu center',
                                    'fallback_cb' => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                                    //Process nav menu using our custom nav walker
                                    'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                                );
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
```

Но есть одно но: не выводится li с классом .divider, хотя просмотрев файл wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php нашел там вот такое вот:

```
if ( strcasecmp( $item->attr_title, 'divider' ) == 0 && $depth === 1 ) {
        $output .= $indent . '<li role="presentation" class="divider">';
    } else if ( strcasecmp( $item->title, 'divider') == 0 && $depth === 1 ) {
        $output .= $indent . '<li role="presentation" class="divider">';
    } else if ( strcasecmp( $item->attr_title, 'dropdown-header') == 0 && $depth === 1 ) {
        $output .= $indent . '<li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">' . esc_attr( $item->title );
    } else if ( strcasecmp($item->attr_title, 'disabled' ) == 0 ) {
        $output .= $indent . '<li role="presentation" class="disabled"><a href="#">' . esc_attr( $item->title ) . '</a>';
    } else {
```

к сожалению в php новичек и посему перепробовал все что только нашел в гугле, но li с классом .divider между ссылками так и не удалось добавить. Буду благодарен если знающие подскажут что надо выставить или изменить чтобы меню приобрело вид:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu center" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Вот это:

> Dividers
>
> Simply add a Link menu item with a URL of # and a Link Text or Title Attribute of divider (case-insensitive so ‘divider’ or ‘Divider’ will both work ) and the class will do the rest.

если что тоже пробовал, та же история. Может есть какая альтернатива как добавить `<li class="divider">` между каждой из ссылок? Jquery? Потому что строка отвечающая за сравнение title с 'divider' явно не работает в этом коде. Либо какие-то непонятки у этого кода с WP 4.5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему решил добавив произвольную ссылку с класом `.divider` включив предварительно в `настройки экрана` `Показывать расширенные свойства меню` отображение классов. И затем добавив css:

```
.divider > a {
display: none !important;
```

}